# How to remove Container View's Border (Xcode Interface Builder)?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, container-view

I've noticed that the `Container View` in Xcode's `Interface Builder` has a shadow and I didn't found any possibility to remove this thin border from the view.
I'm developing for macOS using Xcode 8.3.

How to remove this border?

Comment: Found solution?

Comment: @RoiMulia Not really, just a workaround for my scenario: I had two `Container Views` in a `StackView`, so I set the `spacing` to `0`. But of course it would look nicer without these borders. It would be nice if you would leave an answer for the case you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, If i do I will